# How to create a role to ServiceAccount with context

Tags: kubernetes, role

I want to create a role to service account with context.
My goal is to be able to run `kubectl get pods` with the context of the service account.

To do it I need:

1. Create service account
2. Create role
3. Create bind role
4. Create context

I created a service account:

```
kubectl create serviceaccount myservice
```

**Role.yaml:**

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata: 
  namespace: development
  name: my-role
rules: 
- apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps"]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get"]
```

**BindRole.yaml:**

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata: 
  name: my-role-binding
  namespace: development
subjects: 
- kind: ServiceAccount 
  name: myservice
  namespace: development
  apiGroup: ""
roleRef: 
  kind: Role
  name: my-role
  apiGroup: ""
```

I want to be able to run `kubectl get pods` in the context of the service account `myservice`.

To create context I need something like that:

```
kubectl config set-context myservice-context --cluster=kubernetes --user=???
```

But I can't use `--user` for the service account.
So how can I do it ?

I thought to use `kubectl config set-credentials` but it just creates a user and I already have the service account.

EDIT:
Here is my try to create a user with the token of the service account and then use it with `kubectl --context=myservice-context get pods` but it failed:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the cluster maybe missing from your `~/.kube/config` file. If it were a permissions issue, I would expect to see either `error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)` or `Error from server (Forbidden)`.

The error you are seeing `The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?` implies that there is no cluster with the name you specified in your kubeconfig.

I'd check that your kubeconfig includes the cluster name `kubernetes` with `certificate-authority-data` and respective `server`.

For example here is me attempting with non-existent service account first with an invalid cluster, then again with a cluster that does exist in my `kubeconfig`.

Bad cluster name:

```
kubectl config set-context service-context \
--cluster=doesnotexist \
> --namespace=default \
> --user=service-account
Context "service-context" modified.
➜  ~ kubectl --context=service-context get pods
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Good cluster name:

```
kubectl config set-context service-context \
--cluster=exists \
--namespace=default \
--user=service-account
Context "service-context" modified.
➜  ~ kubectl --context=service-context get pods
error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
```

The later error would suggest there was something wrong with your user/permissions. The former would suggest the `cluster` does not exist in your `kubeconfig`.

EDIT:

Also remember when you use `sudo` its using `/root/.kube/config` which may not be what you want

Comment: Thanks, the problem was with the name of the cluster. It was "minikube" instead of "kubernetes"

Comment: Sure thing. happy to help!